# Biased sorting of array

Tags: node.js, typescript, sorting

I want to sort an array but introduce some bias(?) while sorting.

I have a following interface: `items: Array<{ totalScore: number }>`

Which I want to call like `biasSort(items)` (or `items.sort(biasSort)` for that matter)

The array should be sorted in descending order but should include a bit of randomness/bias which makes it possible for items with a lower `totalScore` to also bubble to the top.

I made a poor-mans implementation as follows

```js
export const biasSort = (items: { totalScore: number }[]) => {
  // Step 1: Sort by descending total scores
  const sortedItems = [...items].sort((a, b) => b.totalScore - a.totalScore);

  // Step 2: Introduce randomness with probability inversely proportional to score difference
  const scores = sortedItems.map(({ totalScore }) => totalScore);
  const maxScoreDifference = Math.max(...scores) - Math.min(...scores);

  // Adjust positions based on probability inversely proportional to score difference
  return [...sortedItems].sort((a, b) => {
    const scoreDifference = b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
    const probability = 1 - scoreDifference / maxScoreDifference;

    // Adjust positions based on probability
    return Math.random() < probability ? 1 : -1;
  });
};
```

this does sort the array as expected and introduces some randomness but there must be a better sollution / existing algorithm to this problem?

Comment: Can't you do a [DSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) type approach with the D being numeric +/- a bias?

Comment: Thanks, I will look at your suggestion! fair warning; I have no experience in this (maths) topic whatsoever.

Comment: Please tag the language you're using, and the environment you're running in, if appropriate